# How to make Paginator with calebporzio/sushi from external data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-pagination

With https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi I try to read data from external source and
convert array with these data into Eloquent Paginator class.

I created a model class app/Models/Point.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

use \Sushi\Sushi;
// My PHPStorm greyed line above as non used - can it be that I need to use some trait or interface ?

class Point extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'cost',
        'info',
    ];

    protected $rows = [
    ];

    public function getRows()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }
    public function addRow(array $rowArray)
    {
        $this->rows[] = $rowArray;
    }

}


public function __invoke($_, array $args)
{
    $first = $args['first'] ?? 1;
    $page  = $args['page'] ?? 1;

    $response = Http::get('https://externalapi.com/points');
    $tempPoints = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    $points     = [];
    $newPoint = new Point();
    $row = 0;
    foreach ($tempPoints as $tempPoint) {
        $newPoint->addRow((array)$tempPoint);
    }

    // Just array written into log file
    $points = $newPoint->getRows();
    \Log::info(' -190 $points::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($points));



    $page  = 1;
    $first = 50;
    $points = Point::offset(0)->limit(1000)->paginate($first, array('*'), 'page', $page);

    \Log::info(' -191 $points::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($points));


    return $points;
}
```

In log file I see empty paginator:

> [2023-04-25 13:54:46] local.INFO: {"current_page":1,"data":[],"first_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000?page=1","from":null,"last_page":1,"last_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=1","links":[{"url":null,"label":"« Previous","active":false},{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=1","label":"1","active":true},{"url":null,"label":"Next »","active":false}],"next_page_url":null,"path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/","per_page":50,"prev_page_url":null,"to":null,"total":0}

Also tracing sql logs I see statement:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS aggregate FROM `points`
```

I suppose that in my model has some invalid configurations and paginate method does not work properly and db is read...

**FIXED BLOCK:**
I remade in app/Models/Point.php

```
class Point extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;
    ...
```

With that changes I do not see any sql-statements, but resulting pagination object has empty data.
I tried 2 ways to get paginated data from Point mode:

```
$points = $newPoint->offset(0)->limit(1000)->paginate($first, array('*'), 'page', $page);
```

OR:

```
$points = Point::offset(0)->limit(1000)->paginate($first, array('*'), 'page', $page);
```

Which is valid way to get paginated data in this case ?

How to fix it ?

Comment: For starters: `use \Sushi\Sushi;` goes within the class. Double-check the docs; your class currently isn't using Sushi at all.

Comment: I used use \Sushi\Sushi declaration in my model. Which declarationdid I miss? Please point

Comment: In your question, the `use \Sushi\Sushi;` line is *before* `class Point extends Model`. You need to move it into the class. Again, see the Sushi docs for placement. (This is why PHPStorm has greyed out the line; it's unused.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

use \Sushi\Sushi;
// My PHPStorm greyed line above as non used - can it be that I need to use some trait or interface ?

class Point extends Model
{
```

should be

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;


class Point extends Model
{
   use \Sushi\Sushi;
```

Comment: Yes, I applied these changes as I wrote in FIXED BLOCK. But I still got empty collection of data